# How to find the longest increasing subsequence?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to use a code to print the  longest increasing subsequence,the code works but it doesn't print the right longest increasing subseqquence .

---

**for example if the input was :3,5,11,8,4,7,1,2,10,12,9,6**

### The output is : [1, 2, 6, 9, 12]

### my desired output is : 3,4,7,10,12

I've debugging the way of inserting and printing the arraylist and its correct , I believe that there is something wrond here,why was is wrong?why it changes the order of numbers!?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> lengthOfsequance(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {

    if (nums == null || nums.size() == 0)
        return null;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int num : nums) 
    {
        if (list.size() == 0 || num > list.get(list.size() - 1)) 
            list.add(num);
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = list.size() - 1;
            while (i < j) 
            {
                int mid = (i + j) / 2;
                if (list.get(mid) < num) 
                    i = mid + 1;
                else
                    j = mid;
            }
           list.set(j, num);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output in your exemple?

Comment: 1,2,6,9,12 is not a sub-sequence of your stated input 3,5,11,8,4,7,1,2,10,12,9,6.

Comment: I think that was his program output, not what he wanted

Comment: what i wanted is 3,4,7,10,12  not  1,2,6,9,12 
also i'm not supposed to change the order of the numbers

Comment: Oh ok i get it now but here, is 3,5,8,10,12 a valid output as well?

Comment: yes , it is a valid output , it doesn't matter with subsequence i choose to print as long as it's the longest

Comment: I appreciate the surprise accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach **can't** work. You are using **one** list to collect the longest sequence. But your input sequence can have **multiple** increasing sequences. Maybe one that goes from index 0 to 5; and another one that goes from index 10 to 20.

In other words; you need a different strategy; and the "straight forward" approach is something like:

1. iterate the input list, to "collect" **all** increasing sequences (in other words: that would be a List of Lists).
2. Afterwards, you look into that List of Lists to find the max-length one

Of course, this can then be further optimized - you don't need to remember **all** increasing sequences, you just have to remember about the "longest completed" sequence that you saw before.

But as said: the first, naive implementation would be to simply identify all "increasing + complete" sequences in the input list. And then you work  your way from there.

( as I assume this is some kind of homework project I am only giving guiding ideas, not source code. Implementation is left as exercise to the reader )

Edit: to address the comment "how to avoid remembering 'equal' sequences".

Assume your input is this sequence: 1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,1,2,3
When you look for increasing sequences in there, you should find:

(1, 2, 3) and (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), and (1, 2, 3)

You are correct: if you represent the above tuples as `List<Integer>`; then "correct" code would collect **three** lists; where the first and third would be **equal** (because they contain the very same numbers).

And when you store those lists within a `List<List<Integer>>` then, yes, your code would have to account for duplicates. *One* way of avoiding that could be to use a `Set<List<Integer>>` instead - because the Set makes sure by nature that all entries stored within that collection are not equal. In other words: when you add two lists with the same content to a Set object, then, in the end, the Set will only contain **one** of those two lists. (one thing to be aware of - when you use a HashSet here, then the order of **add** operations is lost ).

Finally: instead of using `Set<List<Integer>>` you could also you use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` with "key" being the **length** of a sequence; and  "value" being the **first index** within the input list.

In other words: instead of remembering the **whole** sequence, you can as well just remember at which position a sequence starts, and how many elements that sequence has.

Long story short: there are many many different ways to solve this puzzle, using all kinds of data structures and looping/counting mechanisms. So, don't stop with the first working version, but keep playing.

Comment: thank you ! i thought of what you've said , my only problem is when i want to remember all increasing sequesnces how will i know i i'm not all ready remembered this subsequence before ?

Comment: Updated my answer to address that part ... again.

Comment: then , won't it be the complixty is o(2^n) ?

Comment: Sure. Thats why I am saying: you might want to start of with an implementation that is **simple** to create and test. And then you continue to improve your solution. You sure can solve this in O(n) - meaning you only need a single pass over the input array to find the largest increasing sequence in there.